# LDO selection in Thermal point of view

Tags: thermal, ldo, power-dissipation

I need to select a LDO for design with below details

in volt= 15V
Op volt= 5V
op current require = 250mA

I gone through UA78M05IDCYR part (TI), it has thermal data as below
Rtheta JA =53 C/W
Rtheta JC=30.6C/W
Bias current=4mA
Tamb=50C

Pd= (VIn-Vo)*Io+ Vin*Ibias= (15-5)*250 + 4*15 =2560mW

Tj=PdXRtheta JA + Tamb= 2.56*53 + 50 =185C

185C is more than 150C limit of IC ( I should consider 125C max for be in safe regin).

Q1) Is my calculation is right
Q2) If yes then I can not use this part in my design , then why they state output current uptp 500mA in datasheet.
Q3) Do I need to add heat sink ( PCB heatsink)
Q4) what size i need to consider for PCB copper area.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need an LDO (low drop-out) regulator if input is 15V and output is 5V? Any old regulator would fit the bill on this. For instance an 7805 (TO220 package and NOT a LDO regualator) will produce a decent 5V from anything between 7V and 30V. You have to watch power dissipation though because with 15V in and 5V out with 250 mA flowing there is 2.5 watts dissipated hence you'll need a heatsink.

It's the same for LDO regulators so get hung up on the term LDO. Maybe a 5V switching regualtor will better suit your needs if power/heat is a problem.

> why they state output current uptp 500mA in datasheet

They state 500mA output current for the small version of the 7805 because with a low differential voltage between input and output (say 2V) the power dissipation is only 1 watts and potentially doable in a small package with good copper on the PCB surrounding it.